# Xcode , Swift , Table View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, static, tableview, cells

I have intiated a Table View Controller and Designed Static Custom Cells on my storyboard , so when i create a new custom swift file (table view controller class) and add on my table view controller , the table sections gets vanished when i deploy the application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is these delegates. They are provided in the template, and these will remove any static cells in this state. So if you are just using static cells, remove these functions, otherwise modify them to work with dynamic cells as well.

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}
```